# Is it possible to set a drop down widget to be required?

Tags: google-app-maker

Was wondering if it was possible to have a drop down widget in app maker be required. In other words, users could not click submit unless they had selected a value from a down down menu. Kind of like how validation on text boxes.

When looking at the property editor for a drop down widget I don't see anything that will allow me to set the above requirement out of the box.

Below is the property editor for a drop down, you will notice there is no validation options.

Below that is the text box property editor with the validation option expanded. I basically need the same functionality for my drop down menu.

If anyone dealt with a similar issue I would appreciate any input.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you have that option.
Look under DropDown menu you will find option called `allowNull`, deselect that option. Also select `validationDisplay` check box from 'Other' menu and users will have to choose from a drop down menu always.

Below are the screen for your reference,

1. Dropdown menu `allowNull` option,

[image: DropDown]

2. Other menu `validationDisplay` option,

[image: Other]

Comment: Oh snap, I had it set like that. The way I wrote my script is just wrong. (Which triggers once the submit button is clicked.) Changed that and it worked fine. Thanks for the help Darpan.

Comment: Glad to hear that. All the best!!